# Eccentricity of a conic

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[image]

I got this solution, is this right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here equation of ellipse is $$\frac{x^2}{11}+\frac{y^2}{(\frac{55}{27})}=1$$

So, $a^2=11$ and $b^2=\frac{55}{27}\implies e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{5}{27}}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{22}{3}}$

Comment: Just realised that eccentric cant be more than 0<e<1

Comment: For ellipse $0\lt e\lt 1$ and one more thing $\sqrt{1-5}\neq 2$ but $2i$ which is certainly can't be eccentricity of any conic